# How can I not view this dynamic text on my react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an error and a warning on my react application that has the following messages:

```
warning.js:36 Warning: getInitialState was defined on ContentBlock, a plain JavaScript class. 
This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. 
Did you mean to define a state property instead?

App.js:77 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'heading' of null
```

Here is my react code under `App.js`

```
class ContentBlock extends Component {
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      heading: 'hello',
      body: 'world'
    };
  }
  render() {
    <Media>
      <Media.Left>
        <Image src={this.props.src}/>
      </Media.Left>
      <Media.Heading>{this.state.heading}</Media.Heading>
      <Media.Body>
        <p>{this.state.body}</p>
      </Media.Body>
    </Media>
   );
  }
}
```

What I want to know is the correct way to dynamically render text. From the tutorials I was reading it seemed the way to go was to use `state` and  `getInitialState`. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I used `import React, { Component } from 'react';` from the create-react-app official page. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: That did the trick thanks Andrew.